# Duplicate jar (ListenableFuture.class) while migrating to New Place SDK google

Tags: android, google-places-api

I am trying to migrate my Autocomplete widget Places SDK Google to the new one using this [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration). But once I try to generate my release or debug apk start getting the error

```
Duplicate jar entry [com/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture.class]
```

I read couple of stackoverflow questions and other references and found it was caused by duplicate guava (ListenableFuture). App level dependencies are listed below.

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha01
implementation 'androidx.mediarouter:mediarouter:1.1.0-alpha01'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha3'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha03'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.3'
implementation 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:2.3.1'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.razorpay:checkout:1.4.7'
implementation 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2@aar'
implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.5'
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.8'
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex-instrumentation:2.0.0'
```

}

What I have done so far-
1. excluded listenablefuture from places sdk

```
implementation ('com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0'){
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'listenablefuture'
}
```

Result was same. Still Duplicate jar entry error for listenablefuture

2. excluded entire guava from places sdk

   implementation ('com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0'){
       exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
   }

Result was NO error. But apk installed, when i runing my activity containing the autocomplete widget, it get the below error and app crashes.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/common/base/Preconditions;
   at com.google.android.libraries.places.api.Places.initialize(Unknown Source:5)
   at com.google.android.libraries.places.api.Places.initialize(Unknown Source:1)
   at com.proyujan.proyujan.MapLeadActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source:26)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7372)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1218)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3147)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3302)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(Unknown Source)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1891)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7425)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
```

3. Found the listenablefuture module in my appcompat dependency. Did step 1 and 2 also with appcompat but result was same.

Please help. How to solve this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

SOLVED: Finally found a solution. I stated earlier listenable future duplication was found while adding new dependency library for places SDK, duplicate being in the AppCompat library.

I was using the latest AppCompat library and here was the problem. It seems as per google docs, [stable version](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/archive/androidx) is 1.0.0. So once I revert back everything to the stable version, the problem was solved.

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
```

And no need of below:

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'listenablefuture'
}
```

Comment: In my only this helped: configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'listenablefuture'
    }

Comment: As is the case of @MrVasilev, this extra configuration solved it for me after nothing else worked. I believe this is a bit of a "hack" until the Guava and androidx libraries sync up.

Answer (score 14):

new places SDK is working but when you migrate to android x it's not working

so add these below lines in app/build dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation ('com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0'){
        exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'listenablefuture'
    }
}

android {
   configurations{
       all*.exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'listenablefuture'
   }
}
```

Comment: configurations{   all*.exclude ... was enough as i updated above already...i believe it overrides every dependency added... but what if i need listenablefuture say for workmanager etc

Comment: In my case only this: configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'listenablefuture'
    }   helped

Comment: I upgraded my project to androidX and added  `configurations{
    all*.exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'listenablefuture'}` only , and it is working fine

Answer (score 5):

Add this dependency to your build:

```
api 'com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android'
```

Comment: Thanks @alécio-carvalho this helped me although a question arises from this answer, Why did it worked? Can you please explain this since I don't get why this worked 

Comment: @SakshamKhurana I found why it's working. Guava 28.1 depends on v9999 of listanablefuture (LF) but that dependency is empty.

So if you have LF 1.0 only which pulls in the class, then you're fine.

Have you had LF 1.0 and Guava earlier then trouble because both of them contains the class.

LF1.0 + Guava 28.1 (which brings empty LF 9999) results a single LF class again.

See POM <description>: https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.google.guava/listenablefuture/9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava/jar

Answer (score 1):

The solution didn't work for me, but after I updated to 2.0.0 things get fixed, version 1.0.0 was giving the error, so use:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.0.0'
```